# FormulaR1C1 "RC[+1]/RC[+2]" doesn't work with EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel-formula, epplus

The graphics no longer work with the EPPlus version 4.0.5, I upgraded to version 5.8.4 but I find myself with the FormulaR1C1 which no longer works in some cases.

If I assign a FormulaR1C1 that uses the values of cells on the right, the value is always 0. Whereas if I do the same thing using cells on the left, the FormulaR1C1 is well transformed into an address and it rediscover values. Below is an explanatory image of my text. The values of the columns are C and D have the correct value when the calculate is requested.

[Explanatory image of my text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpLzw.png)

```
foreach (ExcelRangeBase c in ws.Cells.Reverse())
{
   ExcelRangeBase newCells = assignCell(c, params);
   if (newCells != null)
   {
      string valeur = (c.Value ?? "").ToString();
      if (valeur.StartsWith("{=") && valeur.EndsWith("}"))
      {
        newCells.FormulaR1C1 = "RC[+1]/RC[+2]"; //Simplify for the example but comes from the decomposition of 'valeur'
     }
     newRanges.Add(newCells);
  }
}

ws.Workbook.CalcMode = ExcelCalcMode.Automatic;
ws.Calculate();
```

I have no errors during the generation. When opening the generated file, I got a corruption error.

Comment: What do you mean by "The graphics no longer work with the EPPlus version 4.0.5"? Maybe this is a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: EPPlus 5 is a commercial product, maybe someone on their support team could help - or you could raise a GiHub issue - seems more likely to be a bug in the product then something someone here can help you with: https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/issues

Comment: @TechInquisitor For the graphic, I use templates. And the series value no longer updates.

Comment: @SBFrancies I know that EPPlus 5 is a commercial product now (for the moment in POC to know if it allows us to find our functionalities). Thanks for the Github link (I thought it was only accessible when we had taken the license and not before).

Comment: What I mean is, why not just stick with EPPlus 4.x? What stopped working and why not keep using a version that did work? The license change in 5.x is another compelling reason to stick with old versions. You could even fork them and continue developing them.

Comment: I found the solution, just remove the + sign which was mandatory in version 4.0.5 of EPPlus and not anymore.

@TechInquisitor The upgrade came with the fact that one of the graphics functionality no longer works (otherwise there was no point in doing so). And by switching to version 5, the problem was solved without having to touch the existing code. There is the cost of the license vs the cost of fixing the bug by a developer.

Comment: @EmelineP Still not understanding what you're saying. "The upgrade came with..." - What upgrade? Why change anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, just remove the + sign which was mandatory in version 4.0.5 of EPPlus and not anymore.